# connecting to sql server with jdbc error

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a sql server via the jdbc driver but keep getting this error:

> Error connecting to the specified data source: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection
>   refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an
>   instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port
>   are not blocked by a firewall.".

My connection string is this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SRVR_SQL:1433;DatabaseName=spotfire_server
```

I've also tried this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.60.12\SRVR_SQL:1433;DatabaseName=spotfire_server
```

and this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=spotfire_server
```

and this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://SRVR_SQL:1433;DatabaseName=spotfire_server
```

but all of them give the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDBC connection failed, error: TCP/IP connection to host failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)

Answer (score 0):

try 10.0.0.2
make sure of the basic things like database password, name , table name.....

Answer (score 0):

Read the error:

> Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP
>   connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Are you sure SQL Server is running locally?  Can you connect to it via SQL Server Admin tools?

Which JDBC driver are you using - Microsoft or jDTS?

Try this URL, assuming the listener is running on 10.10.60.12, the port is 1433, and the schema name is dbName:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.60.12:1433;DatabaseName=dbName
```

Comment: I can connect to it via SSMS and I'm using microsoft JDBC drivers...I tried what you mentioned above but still get the same error