# SQL server connection with spring

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-mvc

I created  a spring mvc application to connect with sqlserver database. I used jtds driver for connection.

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=3PLTest;" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="sa" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="sa" />
</beans:bean>
```

When i am trying to run the server it gives the error.

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect)
Nov 03, 2014 10:33:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/warehouse] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I am using SQLEXPRESS.
How does this happen?

Comment: is your username and password correct? Are you able to directly connect to the database from an sql client?

Comment: yes, I can connect it directly.

Comment: Can you connect using a SQL Client? Have you added the jtds jar, what version of jtds, Java are you using?

Comment: @PiyushMattoo yes. I added jtds 1.3.1, java 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled the TCP/IP protocol to your localhost SQL Server installation?

[SQL Server connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)