# Java Hibernate sql server express connection error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2008

Trying to connect my Java Spring app on Tomcat to my sqlserver express database with Hibernate.

Getting error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection Failed TCP / IP to localhost port 1433.
Error: "Connection refused: connect. Check the connection properties, make
sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP
/ IP connections to port, and make sure that no firewall is blocking TCP 
connections to port. ".
```

Comment: may be you get the answer from here Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed

Comment: i go to Enable TCP/IP Right box and i found it already Enable TCP/IP 1433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your tcp/ip protocol is not 1433, please follow theses instructions and your problem should be gone : 
SqlServer Configuration Manager > Sql server Network configurations > protocols for SQLEXPRESS > right click on TCP/IP > properties > IP Adress > IPALL and change TCP PORT to 1433

Answer (score 0):

in majority of cases its the firewall that blocks it. try disabling it