# JPA to MS SQL Server via Eclipse: Ping Failed

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I have a local MS SQL Server Express 2016 running on 1433. I can connect to it via MS SQL Management Studio and HeidiSQL just fine.

In Eclipse Neon I created a new JPA project. I want to create entities from my DB. So I click on `JPA Tools -> Generate Entities from Tables...`. In the following dialog window I click on the `Add connections...` icon. By searching the internet I found two different approaches for continuing from here:

a) Connection Profile Type: `SQL Server`
b) Connection Profile Type: `Generic JDBC`

a) In the following window I add a new driver, specify the path to my `sqljdbc42.jar` and set all the properties (Driver Class: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`). The weird thing, when I chose this driver, in the `Properties` section nothing shows up and I get the following error:

[image: SQL Server error]

b) Similar to a) I add a new driver, specify the path to the jar file and set all the properties. This time I get one step further: I can press the `Test Connection` button. If I do so however, the window freezes for a few seconds and then shows a `Ping failed!` error.

[image: Ping failed!]

I guess the URL is wrong so I tried a lot of different variations but none of them worked. Here are a few of them (but I tried many more):

> jdbc:sqlserver://MyPcName\SQLEXPRESS:1433
>   jdbc:sqlserver://MyPcName\SQLEXPRESS
>   jdbc:sqlserver://MyPcName\SQLEXPRESS:1433
>   jdbc:sqlserver://MyPcName\SQLEXPRESS
>   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433
>   jdbc:sqlserver://MyPcName\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName=MyDb

As mentioned above, connecting via Management Studio or HeidiSQL works (with the username `test` and no password). And while it should not matter since the server is running locally I tried turning of the firewall and it did not help either.

Comment: for my case, it was actually the sqlserver driver I was using has a higher JRE version my environment.  After switching to another driver with lower JRE, then I ping succeeded

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why a) does not work but I figured out my issue with b). MS SQL Management Studio and HeidiSQL did connect to the database via `named-pipe` instead of tcp and the tcp connection was not actually setup. Following the steps in this answer solved it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24299346/4961688