# jdbc SQLServer Exception

Tags: tcp, hive, sqoop

I'm trying to import data from an **SQL Server** to my HIVE and I get the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host **ip address** databaseName=SherLock2, port 1433 has
>   failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties, check that an
>   instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP
>   connections to the port.".

This is the command I'm trying to run:

```
sqoop import --table Sms --target-dir SherlockData/Sms --username yogevmet --password password --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ipadress databaseName=SherLock2" --split-by UUID --hive-import -hive-table SherLock_2.sms --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
```

I looked up here: [JDBC connection failed, error: TCP/IP connection to host failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)

And everything is set as it suppose to be, does someone have any other suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that is a proper SQL Server JDBC URL, with a **space** between host name/IP and the default DB!?!?!?

Comment: Did you simply test that URL with a JDBC client?

Comment: And yes, this command worked with the previous Hive

Comment: What is a _"previous Hive"_?? Do you mean that the command used to work on server X, but fails on a new server Y in the same Data Center? Or fails on a new server Z in another Data Center?

Comment: You where right, the problem was the space instead of ; Thanks!!