# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory, Connection refused SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jmeter, database-connection

I am trying to setup jmeter for sql server. Getting following error

> Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host
>   localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect.
>   Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL
>   Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the
>   port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a
>   firewall.".)

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Environment variable set to:

```
CLASSPATH
C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar
```

Copied file `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar` to `C:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.3\lib\`

JMETER setting:

`DatabaseURL:jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDb;integratedSecurity=true;
jdbcClassDriver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverdriver`

Comment: I didn't downvoted, did you put the driver in the right case: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the exception message? If not, please do that first.

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I selected it from dropdownlist for class driver.
MarkRotteveel, I have checked, sql server is connecting using ssms and i checked TCP/IP is enabled.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed

Answer (score -1):

This setting resolved the issue:
DatabaseURL:jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDb;integratedSecurity=true;jdbcClassDriver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverdriver

rest was fine, when i have added integratedSecurity=true parameter, it worked perfectly fine.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you have the appropriate validation query selected in JDBC Connection Configuration.