# Microsoft SQL Server: "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."

Tags: java

I tried to connect to Microsoft SQL Server and it gives me the error `Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. ClientConnectionId:f5448d0d-950a-45b3-842f-9d2c6ac86ccd`

When I run `netstat -na` and I found a listening with a port of 1433 but still, the connection with Java doesn't work.

My code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

connnectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;database=Northwind;integratedSecurity=true;";

con = DriverManager.getConnection(connnectionUrl);
```

Full stacktrace:

```
   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. ClientConnectionId:f5448d0d-950a-45b3-842f-9d2c6ac86ccd
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4772)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3581)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3541)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2395)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.Temp.main(Temp.java:18)
```

Comment: Full stacktrace can be useful.

Comment: edited in post. :)

Comment: Your problem still not clear. "connection with java doesn't work" - explain nothing. Why do you think problem in firewall? It will be great if you can post your stacktrace.

Comment: Why are you using MS SQL Server driver for My SQL connection? "I tried to connect to My SQL server" - mistake in description?

Comment: I thought this is the full stack trace I printed ex.printstcktrace in my exception.

Comment: Yes. my mistake I meant my sql in like my sql not "mysql". thank you for that, :)

Comment: Try to replace your host name in connection string to "localhost:1433" or whatever port you are using.

Comment: tried it. Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. ClientConnectionId:f5448d0d-950a-45b3-842f-9d2c6ac86ccd \\ couldn't put full stacktrace in comment not enough characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC connection failed, error: TCP/IP connection to host failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)

Comment: Ok. So original issue is fixed. Follow provided instructions.

Comment: No  Ratish Bansal. I got a different problem. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, Alex step 1 completed. waiting for your instructions. Thank you. :)

Comment: Not an expert with MS SQL. [So can't help](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+mssql+The+login+is+from+an+untrusted+domain+and+cannot+be+used+with+Windows+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Please do not remove parts from your question. Just use edit and add new part.

Comment: Ok. thank you, Alex, you been very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
it was because my PC name and Windows User was in Hebrew, changed it to English and it worked.
also, check in the sql server path there aren't any folders named in Hebrew
Thank you, everyone, who helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

By default MS SQL Server does not listen on outside address. The following link could be helpful

https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213407669-How-to-enable-remote-connections-to-MS-SQL-server-

Comment: I did all that this guide said already I still stuck. in this problem. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow instructions in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)