# Server Exception :234 JDBC SQL server express 127.0.01 port: 1433 Clojure

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, clojure

I got this error when running it in clojure, I'm using SQL Express and a mock database to learn, as for this error I've tried to :

1. make an inbound exception in firewall (port : 1433)
2. change the ipall port : 1433, based on this [thread post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)

but still result in error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError (SQLServerException.java:234)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException (SQLServerException.java:285)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket (IOBuffer.java:2466)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open (IOBuffer.java:672)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper (SQLServerConnection.java:2747)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login (SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal (SQLServerConnection.java:2265)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect (SQLServerConnection.java:1291)
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect (SQLServerDriver.java:881)
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection (DriverManager.java:677)
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection (DriverManager.java:189)
> next.jdbc.connection$get_driver_connection.invokeStatic (connection.clj:141)
> next.jdbc.connection$get_driver_connection.invoke (connection.clj:136)
> next.jdbc.connection$url_PLUS_etc$reify__1134.getConnection (connection.clj:359)
> next.jdbc.connection$make_connection.invokeStatic (connection.clj:385)
> next.jdbc.connection$make_connection.invoke (connection.clj:369)
> next.jdbc.connection$eval1153$fn__1154.invoke (connection.clj:408)
> next.jdbc.protocols$eval910$fn__911$G__901__918.invoke (protocols.clj:24)
> next.jdbc.result_set$eval2030$fn__2038.invoke (result_set.clj:911)
> next.jdbc.protocols$eval942$fn__973$G__933__982.invoke (protocols.clj:33)
> next.jdbc$execute_BANG_.invokeStatic (jdbc.clj:238)
> next.jdbc$execute_BANG_.invoke (jdbc.clj:225)
> clojuresql.core$eval7498.invokeStatic (form-init4745400822415211621.clj:29)
> clojuresql.core$eval7498.invoke (form-init4745400822415211621.clj:29)
> clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7177)
> clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7132)
> clojure.core$eval.invokeStatic (core.clj:3214)
> clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3210)
> nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__6438$fn__6439.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:87)
> clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
> clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
> clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:665)
> clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.invokeStatic (core.clj:1973)
> clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke (core.clj:1973)
> clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
> nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__6438.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:87)
> clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086$fn__9089.invoke (main.clj:437)
> clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086.invoke (main.clj:437)
> clojure.main$repl$fn__9095.invoke (main.clj:458)
> clojure.main$repl.invokeStatic (main.clj:458)
> clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:368)
> clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
> nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invokeStatic (interruptible_eval.clj:84)
> nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:56)
> nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__6469$fn__6473.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:152)
> clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
> nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__6536$fn__6540.invoke (session.clj:202)
> nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__6536.invoke (session.clj:201)
> clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
> java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)

and here's my code

```js
(ns clojuresql.core
  (:require [next.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [hugsql.core :as hugsql]
            [hugsql.adapter.next-jdbc :as adapter]
            [next.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [honeysql.core :as sql]
            [honeysql.helpers :refer :all :as helpers]))

  (def db-sqlserver {:dbtype "sqlserver" :dbname "AdventureWorks"
                   :user "sa" :password "123456789"})

  (def ds (jdbc/get-datasource db-sqlserver))

  (jdbc/execute! ds
                ["show tables"])
```

is there something wrong? please help me... Thank you!

Comment: Have you followed the suggestions in the error message, especially "Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port"?  How did you verify the SQL server was up-and-running at 127.0.0.1 port 1433?

Comment: Did you change the IPall port in SQL Server Configuration Manager? If so you need to restart the SQL Server service for the change to take effect.

Comment: @BipedPhill yes, i had it run, while execute the code, i open SQL Server management studio & connect it to database.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, i changed the IPall port from "" to 1433 in SQL Server Conf Manager & already restart it.

Comment: SSMS can be a deceptive test, especially on localhost, because it could be connecting using the Named Pipes or Shared Memory drivers instead of TCP/IP. If you can connect using Server: `127.0.0.1,1433` with SSMS (which forces TCP/IP) then it's likely a driver setup problem in JRE/Clojure. Or if you have a software firewall running you may need to allow the JRE to make outbound connections (even though it's to localhost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered in here, i need to restart the SQL Server

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/10/sql-server-jdbc-error-tcpip-connection-to-host-failed-port-1433.html#axzz6mcL0VpRF