# How to connect to Azure SQL Server in databricks using windows authentication

Tags: python, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, ssms-2017

The server type is database engine and the authentication type used while connecting through SSMS is Windows authentication, similarly, I want to connect the same database through AZURE Databricks.

I have used this code for the connection

> jdbcHostname = "#####" jdbcPort = "1433" jdbcDatabase = "####" jdbcUsername = "##########" jdbcPassword = "####"
>
> jdbcUrl =
> f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};database={jdbcDatabase};integratedSecurity=true"
> connectionProperties = {    "user": jdbcUsername,
> "authenticationScheme": "NativeAuthentication",    "driver":
> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" }
> jdbcDF =
> spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="######",properties=connectionProperties)

But I am getting this error:

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host #####, port 1433 has failed. Error: &#34;#####. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall
```

So, what should be the Python code for this connection?

SS of the SSMS login page
[image: SSMS login page]

Comment: Have you verified that your server is configured to accept tcp/ip connections?

Comment: hostname,41433 is not correct for jdbc. I'm not sure why you're combining two ports in your url, you want: hostname:port nothing else

Comment: @Xedni how to verify this?

Comment: @user10434309 see if this helps. It has a pretty good walk though.  Also, it being another job. Question might give you some ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed

Comment: Typo above; *another jdbc question

Answer (score 0):

```
 The TCP/IP connection to the host C1ML63563-MS, port 1433 has failed. Error: "C1ML63563-MS. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

The server may not be configured to accept TCP/IP, which could be the reason for the error above. To resolve the issue, enable TCP/IP for the SQL Server as follows:

Go to **SQL Server Configuration Manager**, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and select the protocol. Enable TCP/IP by double-clicking on **TCP/IP** as shown below:

[image]

Additionally, go to **SQL Native Client**, select **Client Protocols**, double-click on TCP/IP, and set **1433** as the **default port** as shown below:

[image]

Restart the SQL server service. After that, as per [this](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/connect-sql-server-using-windows-authentication/m-p/13387#M8078), use a Windows authenticated username and password with the JDBC driver to connect to the SQL database from a Databricks notebook. You can use the code below for the connection:

```
jdbcHostname = "<serverName>"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "<databaseName>"
jdbcUsername = "<WindowsuserName>"
jdbcPassword = "<password>"
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
table = "<tableName>"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName={jdbcDatabase}"
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbcDriver).option("url", jdbcUrl).option("dbtable", table).option("user", jdbcUsername).option("password", jdbcPassword).load()
df.show()
```

You will get the table data as output, as shown below:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed).

Comment: In Databricks I have tried to login using integrated security and this is the error I am getting "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:" and with windows id and password I am getting this error: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user &#39;----&#39;. ClientConnectionId:". Though I know I have access to the SQL server using windows authentication.