# Connect to SQL Server using Datagrip on Windows 11

Tags: sql-server, windows-11, datagrip

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2022 using Datagrip in Windows 11 with Windows Authentication.
These are the data that I have obtained when installing SQL Server and with the systeminfo command in the CMD:
Instance Name: SQLEXPRESS
SQL Administrator: ZEPHYRUS\dkval

```
Host:           localhost
Server Name:    ZEPHYRUS
User:           dkval
Port:           1433
Domain:         WORKGROUP
```

I have already tried the drivers:
**Microsoft SQL Server**
[image]

In Advanced I put:

- integratedSecurity    true

**Microsoft SQL Server(jTds)**
[image]
In Advanced I put:

- domain    WORKGROUP
- USENTLMV2 true

What would be the correct fields to fill in Datagrip?

Comment: jTDS hasn't seen a software release since 2013-10-29. Why aren't you using a modern and supported [JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)?

Comment: When specifying connection details you should only use one of: 1) the port number (preferred), or 2) the instance name. Using an instance name requires an SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol) request be made to the SQL Server Browser Service to resolve the instance name to the port that the instance is listening on, then the client connects to that port. That means the service has to be enabled and running, it has to be accessible via udp/1434, and also adds a small delay and unreliability to the connection process. Much better just to specify the correct port.

Comment: As AlwaysLearning and @Koyasha suggest, I have used only the port without the instance, but I obtained:
The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by to firewall."

Comment: For the above, I enabled TCP port 1433 as well as:

- An Inbound Rule in Windows Firewall

- In SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS, I enabled TCP/IP and in its Properties, in the IP Addresses tab I located two IP addresses that contained the IP Address of my internet connection:
Link-local IPv6 address and IPv4 address and in its TCP Port section I put 1433.

After all this, I restarted the SQL Server Service also in SQL Server Configuration Manager but it still cannot establish a connection.

Answer (score 0):

This setup should be enough (works even without specifying the database):

[image]

Driver:

[image]

Tested on MS SQL Server 2022 and the latest version of DataGrip 2023.3.4.

Comment: What version of MSSQL is shown in the installation path of your SQL Server? (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server). In my case is:
MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to establish the connection by configuring the port according to [Md. Naushad Alam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24299346/8916993).

I had already entered SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS, **but I had edited the IP11 and IP12**, but according to Md. Naushad Alam's answer, the **IPAII has to be edited**, after editing it, I restarted the service and The connection worked.

I will leave the configuration that finally worked:

**SQL Server Configuration Manager**
[image]

**Datagrip**
[image]

Thanks to @AlwaysLearning for explanation about the use of Instance vs Port and to @Koyasha for replicating the connection and specifying the driver version